# Windows 10 - Inaccessible boot device

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning

Sorry if this is long. I've backed up the data at two places.

Windows 10 error INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE

I was trying to dual boot Windows 10 with Xubuntu. Deleted the recovery partition(googled and saw it was ok) and left
untouched Win 7 Loader(200Mb), Win 10 Loader (1MB) and Win 10 partitions(NTFS 140 GB). Free Space is 150GB(partitioned into / and /home ext4, primary, format).
Tried installing Xubuntu but Grub install failed and now Windows 10 won't boot.

Created a separate recovery USB from another Windows 10 laptop but that has option of deleting all my files to recover the OS.

When Automatic Repair launches, the options are:

1. Troubleshoot

   - Recover from a drive

     - Just remove my files. Tried and it tries to start recovery process but will delete all my user accounts and personal files) so didn't proceed
     - Full clean the drive. Didn't try this yet
   - Advanced Options

     - System Restore(doesn't work)
     - System Image Recovery(Windows cannot find a system image on this computer)
     - Startup Repair(SR couldn't repair your PC. Log file: None
     - Command Prompt(X drive:)
     - Go back to previous version(can't go back)
2. Turn off your PC.

I tried dual boot Xubuntu since I've wasted hours due to the broken Windows Update process. But Windows 7 was paid for and free upgraded to Windows 10 and so I need to get back to it. I've good experience with dual booting and with Linux and I dual booted twice successfully within the past 24 hours. Windows 10 has caused me more problems than 3.1, 95, 98, 2000, XP, Vista, and 7 **combined**. I haven't used 8.

Can I recover my data and OS?

Comment: When you boot your pc, what do you see, grub or windows bootloader? If you're using a UEFI bios, that complicates things, but should be as simple to fix as a legacy-based bootloader. If you have recovery media premade, I recommend booting into it, clicking repair, finding command prompt, and running the following commands: `bootrec /FixMbr`, `bootrec /FixBoot`, `bootrec /RebuildBcd`. Once you've done that, reboot. If that doesn't work, you have bigger issues that I assume only a liveCD and an external HDD can help you solve.

Comment: Windows bootloader since grub install failed. My Xubuntu install failed - a first.

Comment: Assuming you're using a UEFI-based system, you most likely overwrote something important in the boot partition while installing xUbu. Unless you can find a bootable tool to repair it, like bootrepair, you may need to create an ubuntu liveCD and attempt to backup whatever data you can from the windows partition, though that feels like a defeat. If you can run the commands I've listed above, I'd like to know if they work in this situation.

Comment: The commands do not work. C: lists only efi, boot, sources directory. And bootmgr.efi, bootmgr, reagent.xml.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-uefi-boot/#Fix_UEFI_Boot_in_Windows_8_81_or_10) may be of use.

Comment: `volume 0 e no_label no_fs dvd-rom 0B no media`  
`volume 1 c recovery fat 32 removable 29gb healthy`  
`volume 2 d no_label no_fs removable 0B No Media`

Comment: DISKPART> list disk lists Disk 0 as Invalid and it is 298 GB. Disk 1 is Online and is 29 GB.

Comment: Unless you have a special setup, I assume Disk 0 is your primary disk and Disk 1 is a USB. What's the partition map of Disk 0 look like? Have you tried selecting Disk 0 and running the mbr fixer on it?

Comment: Disk 0 is primary, Disk 1 is USB. But Disk 0 is marked Invalid and list volume is shows the volumes above. So basically the hard drive is not accessible. I tried Online and Rescan and now it won't even list Disk 0 (298GB) if i try list disk or list vol

Comment: Then a LiveCD may be your only hope. If you can mount the disk in the LiveCD, you can copy your files from it to an external drive. Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Comment: I was able to get everything out using the Xubuntu Live CD and repair and update Windows 10 on which I am typing this comment. Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: Please remember to post that as the answer to your question to help future instances of this issue!

Answer (score 0):

The steps listed in the comments are useful and may work for some, but in the end I got the data out with the Xubuntu Live CD(try without install option) and recovered Windows 10 using a recovery USB. I recommend:

1. Creating a recovery usb for Windows 10 and keeping it in a safe place. Recovery USB created from one laptop will work on another. Takes up about 4-8 GB.
2. Backup your data. I had but was not sure if i had missed anything so was quite concerned.
3. Follow the steps in the comments above.